# Background image not Covering Background Laravel

Tags: php, html, css, laravel, laravel-4

I have been combing the web for what seems like it should be a pretty simple process. I am looking to simply assign an image from my server as the background to a page I am working on via CSS. I am somewhat new to the Laravel framework so this is probably a little different here?

I currently have the following CSS defining my pages body (including the background image):

```
body {
  overflow:auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: transparent url('.../img/giant_back_hi.jpg') no-repeat center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -webkit-filter: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;  
}
```

And the following view element to read it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,300italic,400italic,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/layout.css" />
    <title>my-app</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    @include("header")
    <div class="content">
      <div class="container">
        @yield("content")
      </div>
    </div>
    @include("footer")
  </div>
</html>
```

Whenever I try to render the page everything works great but the background returns blank. Any idea as to what I am missing or how to correctly code this?

My directory map is as follows:

```
public
--css
----layout.css
--img
----giant_back_hi.jpg
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

**EDIT**
I've determined that when I apply a quantitative height value to the height property in css ie. (`height:1200px;`) the image displays.

So, the image is showing up it is just not covering the page as I told it too... it's hidden by my header until i manually resize it.

Comment: I'm guessing it is because of this typo: `url('.../img/giant_back_hi.jpg')`. Note the 3 points instead of 2 at the start of the URL.

Comment: @kajetons sorry, I do have 3 points.. should I have two? Tried that same issue.

Comment: You can use your favorite browser (Firefox or Chrome both work), press F12 to open Developer Tools, hover on element body, then see the real url of background-img, to see if that point to exact url that you want.
Just like that, you can get the problem and then find the solution.

Comment: On second glance it seems to be pulling from where it is supposed to be. @Tuanitim. Even when I click open the path in a new tab in chrome it open the right image.. its calling correctly just not displaying.

Comment: Seeing your project structure, just try this:
background: transparent url('img/giant_back_hi.jpg')...

Comment: @Tuanitim see my edit! Thanks! it is working just a sizing issue!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're serving your site with the `public/` folder in your installation as the root, so the contents of your `public/css/` and `public/img/` folders are accessible to the HTML and CSS in your views, via `/css/` and `/img/`.

In this case the root directory (`/`) from the perspective of the HTML is your `public/` directory, so, in your HTML, update the link to your css:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/layout.css" />
```

and in your css:

```
background: transparent url('/img/giant_back_hi.jpg') no-repeat center center;
```